# How to remove gap between first 2 columns?

Tags: tables, formatting

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \caption{XYZ}

\begin{tabular}{lrrrrrrr}
\toprule
Alloy & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Process} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Author} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Condition} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Microstructure} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{YS [MPa]} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{UTS [MPa]} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{EL [\%]} \\
\midrule
Ti-6Al-4V & \multicolumn{1}{l}{SLM/LBM} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Facchini et al. } & \multicolumn{1}{l}{AF} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Acicular $\upalpha'$} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1040±10p} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1140±10p} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{8.1 ± 0.3\^p} \\
      &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Rafi et al.} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{AF} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Martensitic $\upalpha'$ in columnar prior $\upbeta$} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1143v} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1219v} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{4.89v} \\
      &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1195h} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1269h} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5h} \\
      &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Koike et al.} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{AF} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textcolor[rgb]{ .133,  .133,  .133}{$\upalpha-\upalpha'$ martensite and twinned $\upalpha$}} & 840   & 930   & 6.8 \\
      &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Vilaro et al.} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{AF} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textcolor[rgb]{ .133,  .133,  .133}{Fine acicular $\upalpha'$}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1137±20v} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1206±8v} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{7.6±2v} \\
      &       &       &       & \textcolor[rgb]{ .133,  .133,  .133}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{962±47} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1166±25} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1.7±0.3} \\
      & \multicolumn{1}{l}{LMD} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Carroll et al.} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{AF} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textcolor[rgb]{ .133,  .133,  .133}{Prior $\upbeta$ with $\upalpha$ grain boundary}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{960±26h} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1063±20h} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{13.3±1.8} \\
      &       &       &       & \textcolor[rgb]{ .133,  .133,  .133}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{970±17lower part} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1087±8} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{17.6±0.7} \\
      &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textcolor[rgb]{ .133,  .133,  .133}{Acicular $\upalpha$}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{945±13 upper part} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1041±12} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{18.7±1.7} \\
      &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Amsterdam and Kool} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{AF} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textcolor[rgb]{ .133,  .133,  .133}{Acicular}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1052±27} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1153±13} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5.3±2.1} \\
      &       &       &       & \textcolor[rgb]{ .133,  .133,  .133}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1045±24} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1141±15} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{9.2±1.1} \\
      & \multicolumn{1}{l}{EBM} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Murr et al. } & \multicolumn{1}{l}{AF} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Coarse $\upalpha$-plates} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{v1115} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{v1120} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{v25} \\
      &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Fine/coarse $\upalpha$-plates} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{v1110} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{v1115} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{v16} \\
      &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Rafi et al.} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{AF} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Primary $\upalpha$ along with $\upbeta$ on boundary} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{869v} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{928v} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{9.9v} \\
      &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{899h} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{978h} & 9.5 \\
\textcolor[rgb]{ .133,  .133,  .133}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Koike et al.} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{AF} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Acicular $\upalpha$-plates, fine $\upalpha-\upbeta$ lamellar} & 750   & 780   & 2.3 \\
      & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Cast} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Koike et al.} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{AF} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Coarse $\upalpha-\upbeta$ lamellar} & 750   & 850   & 4.5 \\
      &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Vilaro et al.} &       &       & 865   & 980   & 13.5 \\
      &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{ASTM F1108} &       &       & 758   & 860   & \multicolumn{1}{l}{>8} \\
      &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
      & \multicolumn{1}{l}{WAAM} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Wang et al.} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{AF} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Coarse acicular $\upalpha$-plates} & 950   & 1033  & 11.7 \\
      & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Wrought} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Murr et al. } &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Coarse $\upalpha$-plates} & 1170  & 1230  & 12 \\
      &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Equiaxed $\upalpha/\upbeta$} & 1220  & 1290  & 14 \\
      &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Facchini et al. } &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{$\upalpha$-globular in $\upalpha+\upbeta$} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{790±20p} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{870±10p} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{18.1±0.8p} \\
      &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Koike et al. } &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Fine $\upalpha-\upbeta$ lamellar} & 850   & 940   & 14 \\
\midrule
AF: as fabricated, h: perpendicular to build direction, v: in build direction &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{landscape}
```

[image]

Comment: the image shown is not made by the code that you posed (different caption) please make a small _complete_ document that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: why do you have every entry in a `\multicolumn{1}{l}...` you can remove all of them, which would make the code a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

cause of your problem is the following table line:

```
AF: as fabricated, h: perpendicular to build direction, v: in build direction &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
```

replace it with

```
\multicolumn{8}{l}{AF: as fabricated, h: perpendicular to build direction, v: in build direction}\\
```

and you will obtain desired result. however, it seems that your table is generated with some table generator, consequently it contain a lot of clutter. for further help you should provide complete small document in which preamble has only to table relevant packages. so far i obtain the following result:

[image]

above table i generate with following mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{XYZ}
    \centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{}*{8}{l}@{}}
    \toprule
Alloy
    & Process   & Author            & Cond. & Microstructure
        & YS [MPa]  & UTS [MPa] & EL [\%]       \\
    \midrule
Ti-6Al-4V
    & SLM/LBM   & Facchini et al.   & AF
        & Acicular $\alpha'$    & 1040±10p  & 1140±10p  & 8.1 ± 0.3\^p      \\
%
    &           & Rafi et al.       & AF
        & Martensitic $\alpha'$ in columnar prior $\beta$
                                & 1143v     & 1219v     & 4.89v             \\
%
    &           &                   &
        &                       & 1195h     & 1269h     & 5h                \\
%
    &           & Koike et al.      & AF
        &  $\alpha-\alpha'$ martensite and twinned $\alpha$
                                & 840       & 930       & 6.8               \\
%
    &           & Vilaro et al.     & AF
        & Fine acicular $\alpha'$
                                & 1137±20v  & 1206±8v   & 7.6±2v            \\
%
      &       &       &       &     & 962±47    & 1166±25   & 1.7±0.3       \\
%
      & LMD & Carroll et al.        & AF
        & Prior $\beta$ with $\alpha$ grain boundary
                                & 960±26h       & 1063±20h  & 13.3±1.8      \\
      &       &       &       &     & 970±17lower part
                                                & 1087±8    & 17.6±0.7      \\
%
    &       &       &       & Acicular $\alpha$
                                    & 945±13 upper part
                                                & 1041±12   & 18.7±1.7      \\
%
    &       & Amsterdam and Kool  & AF
        & Acicular                  & 1052±27   & 1153±13   & 5.3±2.1       \\
    &       &       &       &       & 1045±24   & 1141±15   & 9.2±1.1       \\
%
    & EBM   & Murr et al.           & AF
        & Coarse $\alpha$-plates    & v1115     & v1120     & v25           \\
%
    &       &       &
        & Fine/coarse $\alpha$-plates
                                    & v1110     & v1115     & v16           \\
%
    &       & Rafi et al.       & AF
        & Primary $\alpha$ along with $\beta$ on boundary
                                    & 869v      & 928v      & 9.9v          \\
      &       &       &       &     & 899h      & 978h      & 9.5           \\
%
   &       & Koike et al.       & AF
        & Acicular $\alpha$-plates, fine $\alpha-\beta$ lamellar
                                    & 750       & 780       & 2.3           \\
%
    & Cast    & Koike et al.    & AF
        & Coarse $\alpha-\beta$ lamellar
                                    & 750       & 850       & 4.5           \\
%
    &         & Vilaro et al. & &   & 865       & 980       & 13.5          \\
%
    &       & ASTM F1108      & &   & 758       & 860       & >8            \\
%
      \addlinespace
%
    & WAAM    & Wang et al.   & AF
        & Coarse acicular $\alpha$-plates
                                    & 950       & 1033      & 11.7          \\
%
    & Wrought & Murr et al.   &
        & Coarse $\alpha$-plates    & 1170      & 1230      & 12            \\
%
    &       &       &
        & Equiaxed $\alpha/\beta$   & 1220      & 1290      & 14            \\
%
    &       & Facchini et al.
        &       & $\alpha$-globular in $\alpha+\beta$
                                    & 790±20p   & 870±10p   & 18.1±0.8p     \\
%
    &       & Koike et al.        &
        & Fine $\alpha-\beta$ lamellar
                                    & 850       & 940       & 14            \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{8}{l}{AF: as fabricated, h: perpendicular to build direction, v: in build direction}\\
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The huge white space between the first and second column is caused by the width of the notes underneath the `\bottomrule`. In the following example, I have enclosed these notes in a `multicolumn` that is 8 columns wide. Additionally, I have removed the unneccecary `\multicolumn{1}{l}` commands that seem to originate from a table generator.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{ .133,  .133,  .133} 
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape} 
\begin{table}[ht] 
\centering 
\caption{XYZ}
\begin{tabular}{lllllrrr}
\toprule
Alloy & Process & Author & Condition & Microstructure & YS [MPa] &UTS [MPa] & EL [\%] \\
\midrule
Ti-6Al-4V & SLM/LBM & Facchini et al.  & AF & Acicular $\upalpha'$ &1040$\pm$10p & 1140$\pm$10p & 8.1 $\pm$ 0.3\^p \\
      &       &Rafi et al.& AF & Martensitic $\upalpha'$ in columnar prior $\upbeta$ & 1143v & 1219v & 4.89v \\
      &       &       &       &       & 1195h & 1269h & 5h \\
      &       &  Koike et al. &  AF &  \textcolor{mycolor}{$\upalpha-\upalpha'$ martensite and twinned $\upalpha$} & 840   & 930   & 6.8 \\
      &       &  Vilaro et al. &  AF &  \textcolor{mycolor}{Fine acicular $\upalpha'$} &  1137$\pm$20v &  1206$\pm$8v &  7.6$\pm$2v \\
      &       &       &       & \textcolor{mycolor}{} &  962$\pm$47 &  1166$\pm$25 &  1.7$\pm$0.3 \\
      &  LMD &  Carroll et al. &  AF &  \textcolor{mycolor}{Prior $\upbeta$ with $\upalpha$ grain boundary}&  960$\pm$26h &  1063$\pm$20h &  13.3$\pm$1.8 \\
      &       &       &       & \textcolor{mycolor}{} &  970$\pm$17 lower part &  1087$\pm$8 &  17.6$\pm$0.7 \\
      &       &       &       &  \textcolor{mycolor}{Acicular $\upalpha$} &  945$\pm$13 upper part &  1041$\pm$12 &  18.7$\pm$1.7 \\
      &       &  Amsterdam and Kool &  AF &  \textcolor{mycolor}{Acicular} &  1052$\pm$27 &  1153$\pm$13 &  5.3$\pm$2.1 \\
      &       &       &       & \textcolor{mycolor}{} &  1045$\pm$24 &  1141$\pm$15 &  9.2$\pm$1.1 \\
      &  EBM &  Murr et al.  &  AF & Coarse $\upalpha$-plates &  v1115 &  v1120 &  v25 \\
      &       &       &       &  Fine/coarse $\upalpha$-plates &  v1110 &  v1115 &  v16 \\
      &       &  Rafi et al. &  AF &  Primary $\upalpha$ along with $\upbeta$ on boundary &  869v &  928v &  9.9v \\
      &       &       &       &       &  899h &  978h & 9.5 \\
\textcolor{mycolor}{} &       &  Koike et al. &  AF &  Acicular $\upalpha$-plates, fine $\upalpha-\upbeta$ lamellar & 750   & 780   & 2.3 \\
      &  Cast &  Koike et al. &   AF &  Coarse $\upalpha-\upbeta$ lamellar & 750   & 850   & 4.5 \\
      &       &  Vilaro et al. &       &       & 865   & 980   & 13.5 \\
      &       &  ASTM F1108 &       &       & 758   & 860   &  $>$8 \\
      &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
      &  WAAM &  Wang et al. &   AF &  Coarse acicular $\upalpha$-plates & 950   & 1033  & 11.7 \\
      &  Wrought &  Murr et al. &       &  Coarse $\upalpha$-plates & 1170  & 1230  & 12 \\
      &       &       &       &  Equiaxed $\upalpha/\upbeta$ & 1220  & 1290  & 14 \\
      &       &  Facchini et al. &       &  $\upalpha$-globular in $\upalpha+\upbeta$ &  790$\pm$20p &  870$\pm$10p &  {18.1$\pm$0.8p} \\
      &       &  Koike et al.  &       &  Fine $\upalpha-\upbeta$ lamellar & 850   & 940   & 14 \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{8}{l}{AF: as fabricated, h: perpendicular to build direction, v: in build direction}\\
\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:addlabel}% 
\end{table}% 
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

In the following example, I have taken the freedom to do some more modifications: I have used the `threeparttable` package to include the table notes with a better spacing. Additionally, I have used the flexible width `X` column from  the `tabularx` package for the column 'Microstructure', so that the table does not exceed the textwidth. Lastly, I have removed the first column and suggest that you include this information in the caption, as this column is not really needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{ .133,  .133,  .133} 

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape} 
\begin{table}[ht] 
\centering 
\caption{Ti-6Al-4V}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lllXrrr}
\toprule
  Process & Author & Condition & Microstructure & YS [MPa] &UTS [MPa] & EL [\%] \\
\midrule
  SLM/LBM & Facchini et al.  & AF & Acicular $\upalpha'$ &1040$\pm$10p & 1140$\pm$10p & 8.1 $\pm$ 0.3\^p \\
            &Rafi et al.& AF & Martensitic $\upalpha'$ in columnar prior $\upbeta$ & 1143v & 1219v & 4.89v \\
            &       &       &       & 1195h & 1269h & 5h \\
             &  Koike et al. &  AF &  \textcolor{mycolor}{$\upalpha-\upalpha'$ martensite and twinned $\upalpha$} & 840   & 930   & 6.8 \\
             &  Vilaro et al. &  AF &  \textcolor{mycolor}{Fine acicular $\upalpha'$} &  1137$\pm$20v &  1206$\pm$8v &  7.6$\pm$2v \\
             &       &       & \textcolor{mycolor}{} &  962$\pm$47 &  1166$\pm$25 &  1.7$\pm$0.3 \\
        LMD &  Carroll et al. &  AF &  \textcolor{mycolor}{Prior $\upbeta$ with $\upalpha$ grain boundary}&  960$\pm$26h &  1063$\pm$20h &  13.3$\pm$1.8 \\
             &       &       & \textcolor{mycolor}{} &  970$\pm$17 lower part &  1087$\pm$8 &  17.6$\pm$0.7 \\
             &       &       &  \textcolor{mycolor}{Acicular $\upalpha$} &  945$\pm$13 upper part &  1041$\pm$12 &  18.7$\pm$1.7 \\
             &  Amsterdam and Kool &  AF &  \textcolor{mycolor}{Acicular} &  1052$\pm$27 &  1153$\pm$13 &  5.3$\pm$2.1 \\
             &       &       & \textcolor{mycolor}{} &  1045$\pm$24 &  1141$\pm$15 &  9.2$\pm$1.1 \\
        EBM &  Murr et al.  &  AF & Coarse $\upalpha$-plates &  v1115 &  v1120 &  v25 \\
             &       &       &  Fine/coarse $\upalpha$-plates &  v1110 &  v1115 &  v16 \\
             &  Rafi et al. &  AF &  Primary $\upalpha$ along with $\upbeta$ on boundary &  869v &  928v &  9.9v \\
             &       &       &       &  899h &  978h & 9.5 \\
      &  Koike et al. &  AF &  Acicular $\upalpha$-plates, fine $\upalpha-\upbeta$ lamellar & 750   & 780   & 2.3 \\
        Cast &  Koike et al. &   AF &  Coarse $\upalpha-\upbeta$ lamellar & 750   & 850   & 4.5 \\
             &  Vilaro et al. &       &       & 865   & 980   & 13.5 \\
           &  ASTM F1108 &       &       & 758   & 860   &  $>$8 \\
            &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
        WAAM &  Wang et al. &   AF &  Coarse acicular $\upalpha$-plates & 950   & 1033  & 11.7 \\
        Wrought &  Murr et al. &       &  Coarse $\upalpha$-plates & 1170  & 1230  & 12 \\
             &       &       &  Equiaxed $\upalpha/\upbeta$ & 1220  & 1290  & 14 \\
             &  Facchini et al. &       &  $\upalpha$-globular in $\upalpha+\upbeta$ &  790$\pm$20p &  870$\pm$10p &  {18.1$\pm$0.8p} \\
             &  Koike et al.  &       &  Fine $\upalpha-\upbeta$ lamellar & 850   & 940   & 14 \\
\midrule
\end{tabularx}%
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\begin{tablenotes}
\item AF: as fabricated, h: perpendicular to build direction, v: in build direction
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable} 
\end{table}% 
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Some notes: As there was no documentclass included in your example, and I don't know the margin size of your document, the table might or might not (as in the above example) fit onto your page within the margins. You therefore might need some further adjustments. 
You should also rethink the parts where you used `\textcolor` as such a dark gray color is hardly distinguishable from the black text. Lastly, you should rethink the alignment of the contents in the last three columns.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to (a) wrapping the final row in a `\multicolumn{8}{l}{...}` directive and (b) getting rid of the multitude of utterly pointless `\multicolumn{1}{l}{...}` wrappers, you should also (c) render the final three columns in automatic math mode and (d) strive to organize the header material more clearly. The solution shown below also uses a `tabular*` environment instead of the "basic' `tabular` environment, to assure that the table takes up the full available width.

A separate comment (not addressed in the solution shown below): you may also wish to ask yourself if it's necessary to use `\upalpha` and `\upbeta` instead of the "plain" `\alpha` and `\beta` characters.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=3cm]{geometry} % set page parameters appropriately
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{rotating,booktabs,xcolor,array,siunitx,upgreek}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}} % "c" column w/ automatic math mode

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{XYZ}
\label{tab:addlabel}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % make LaTeX determine appropr. whitespace amounts
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
       llll >{\color[rgb]{.133,.133,.133}}l CCC}
\toprule
Alloy & Process & Author & Condition & Microstructure 
& \mathrm{YS} & \mathrm{UTS} & \mathrm{EL}\\
& & & & & [\si{\mega\pascal}] & [\si{\mega\pascal}] & [\%]\\
\midrule
Ti-6Al-4V & SLM/LBM & Facchini et al. & AF & Acicular $\upalpha'$ & 1040\pm10p & 1140\pm10p & 8.1\pm0.3\hat{p} \\
  & & Rafi et al. & AF & Martensitic $\upalpha'$ in columnar prior $\upbeta$ & 1143v & 1219v & 4.89v \\
  & & & & & 1195h & 1269h & 5h \\
  & & Koike et al. & AF & $\upalpha$-$\upalpha'$ martensite and twinned $\upalpha$ & 840 & 930 & 6.8 \\
  & & Vilaro et al. & AF & Fine acicular $\upalpha'$ & 1137\pm20v & 1206\pm8v & 7.6\pm2v \\
  & & & & & 962\pm47 & 1166\pm25 & 1.7\pm0.3 \\
  & LMD & Carroll et al. & AF & Prior $\upbeta$ with $\upalpha$ grain boundary & 960\pm26h & 1063\pm20h & 13.3\pm1.8  \\
  & & & & & 970\pm17 \text{ lower part} & 1087\pm8 & 17.6\pm0.7 \\
  & & & & Acicular $\upalpha$ & 945\pm13 \text{ upper part} & 1041\pm12 & 18.7\pm1.7 \\
  & & Amsterdam and Kool & AF & Acicular & 1052\pm27 & 1153\pm13 & 5.3\pm2.1 \\
  & & & & & 1045\pm24 & 1141\pm15 & 9.2\pm1.1 \\
  & EBM & Murr et al. & AF & Coarse $\upalpha$-plates & v1115 & v1120 & v25 \\
  & & & & Fine/coarse $\upalpha$-plates & v1110 & v1115 & v16 \\
  & & Rafi et al. & AF & Primary $\upalpha$ along with $\upbeta$ on boundary & 869v & 928v & 9.9v \\
  & & & & & 899h & 978h & 9.5 \\
  & & Koike et al. & AF & Acicular $\upalpha$-plates, fine $\upalpha$-$\upbeta$ lamellar & 750 & 780 & 2.3 \\
  & Cast & Koike et al. & AF & Coarse $\upalpha$-$\upbeta$ lamellar & 750 & 850 & 4.5 \\
  & & Vilaro et al. & & & 865 & 980 & 13.5 \\
  & & ASTM F1108 & & & 758 & 860 & >8 \\ 
\addlinespace % empty line
  & WAAM & Wang et al. & AF & Coarse acicular $\upalpha$-plates & 950 & 1033 & 11.7 \\
  & Wrought & Murr et al. & & Coarse $\upalpha$-plates & 1170 & 1230 & 12 \\
  & & & & Equiaxed $\upalpha/\upbeta$ & 1220 & 1290 & 14 \\
  & & Facchini et al. & & $\upalpha$-globular in $\upalpha{+}\upbeta$ & 790\pm20p & 870\pm10p & 18.1\pm0.8p \\
  & & Koike et al. & & Fine $\upalpha$-$\upbeta$ lamellar & 850 & 940 & 14 \\
\bottomrule\addlinespace
\multicolumn{8}{l}{AF: as fabricated; $h$: perpendicular to build direction, $v$: in build direction}\\
\end{tabular*}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```